# Multiple where criteria or confusion

Tags: sql

I’ve got the following problem sql query I need help with as I can’t get my head around it.

I’m trying to retrieve a list of lessons for my booking table, the only thing is I need to make sure that the lessons are still valid as I have an override table which can do two things.

1. When a class goes on a trip, I want to override the lessons from displaying, so I have included a start date and and end date. If the lessons fall into this range than I don’t want to retrieve the lessons.

2 I have a isNoMoreLesson boolean field in my override table. If class has finished, I want to permanently exclude tripping this previously booked lessons

```
SELECT DISTINCT LessonSubset.SubjectName, 
LessonSubset.Day, 
LessonSubset.StartTime, 
LessonSubset.EndTime, 
LessonSubset.fk_PeriodInformationID 

FROM LessonSubset

LEFT JOIN OverrideLesson ON 
(LessonSubset.fk_ResourceID = OverrideLesson.fk_ResourceID AND 
LessonSubset.fk_PeriodInformationID = OverrideLesson.fk_PeriodInformationID) 

WHERE LessonSubset.fk_ResourceID = ‘XABCDE' AND LessonSubset.Day = ‘Mon' AND
(OverrideLesson.isNoMoreLesson != 1 OR booking_date < OverrideLesson.EndDate AND
booking_date< OverrideLesson.StartDate) 

ORDER BY  LessonSubset.Day ASC
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Is this returning you invalid results or an error? I'm assuming invalid results...if so, are you getting too many results or not enough?

Comment: Im getting no results, at all.

Comment: You are transforming your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` by including `OverrideLesson` in your `WHERE` clause.  You need to move `(OverrideLesson.isNoMoreLesson != 1 OR booking_date < OverrideLesson.EndDate AND
booking_date< OverrideLesson.StartDate) ` to the `ON` clause for the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: The way it's written right now, because there are WHERE conditions on OverrideLesson, a LessonSubset MUST have matching records in OverrideLesson or it won't return anything.  I think you might want to do something like `WHERE OverrideLesson.ID IS NULL OR (the rest of your OvverrideLesson clauses)`.  That will return where a Lesson doesn't have any Overrides OR where it does have an Override but your conditions didn't match.

Comment: Also, @Siyual's comment is not only correct but probably a more "acceptable" version of what I suggested.  It will filter out rows faster so the Where clause only applies to a smaller subset.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a left join, you should not put a WHERE clause on the left joined table (or you will get the same result as an inner join).

So either you want a left join (than put the clauses on overrideLesson in  the left join clause), or do an inner join.

As you get only data from LessonSubset and want to exclude data depending on OverrideLesson restrictions, I think you want an inner join.

Then, you have a mix of "OR" and "AND", which might give you some weird results,if you don't take care of precedence order (you should rather put parenthesis). And I guess (but it's not that clear) that your AND /OR logic is not what you want.

So

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  LessonSubset.SubjectName, 
  LessonSubset.Day, 
  LessonSubset.StartTime, 
  LessonSubset.EndTime, 
  LessonSubset.fk_PeriodInformationID 

FROM LessonSubset

LEFT JOIN OverrideLesson ON 
  LessonSubset.fk_ResourceID = OverrideLesson.fk_ResourceID AND 
  LessonSubset.fk_PeriodInformationID = OverrideLesson.fk_PeriodInformationID AND
  --include the restrictions in the left join, and change the "and / or logic"
  OverrideLesson.isNoMoreLesson != 1 AND 
  --take only if booking_date is out of range
  (booking_date > OverrideLesson.EndDate OR booking_date < OverrideLesson.StartDate)

WHERE LessonSubset.fk_ResourceID = 'XABCDE' AND LessonSubset.Day = 'Mon'

ORDER BY  LessonSubset.Day ASC
```

EDIT :
If you wanna exclude some results, it might be clearer to use a NOT EXISTS clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ls.SubjectName, 
  ls.Day, 
  ls.StartTime, 
  ls.EndTime, 
  ls.fk_PeriodInformationID 

FROM LessonSubset ls
WHERE ls.fk_ResourceID = 'XABCDE' AND ls.Day = 'Mon'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                FROM OverrideLesson ol
                WHERE 
                ls.fk_ResourceID = ol.fk_ResourceID AND 
                ls.fk_PeriodInformationID = ol.fk_PeriodInformationID AND
                ol.isNoMoreLesson != 1 AND 
                (booking_date > ol.EndDate OR booking_date < ol.StartDate))

ORDER BY  ls.Day ASC
```

Comment: That last piece missing is the WHERE OverrideLesson.PrimaryKeyField is null.  the OP asked to not have them shown so it would be my assumption you want to rule out and remove any matched records between LessonSubset and OverrideLesson

Comment: @Matt Well, I write about that in my answer :  in that case an inner join would be enough (or better, use a NOT EXISTS clause instead of a join)

Comment: No because he wanted to exclude/remove the matches from the dataset.  So my understanding of question only records that have not been overriden should be returned.  When doing a left join if there is not match the primary key of the right sided table will be NULL when no match.  So the affect is you eliminate all records that are a match between the tables it does not become an inner join

Comment: @Matt Right, I see, not still sure It would be ok with the flag and the range in that case ;)

Comment: The later with NOT Exists will have a performance impact over just using LEFT JOIN pattern.  On a small DB you probably won't notice the difference but in a larger environment it will become clear fast.

Comment: I've tried both examples, and not having much luck. The first example gets me the results I almost want, until I add   (booking_date > OverrideLesson.EndDate OR booking_date < OverrideLesson.StartDate) in the left join in which case I get null results.

Comment: @JK36 I think the best thing to do would be to add a little sample of your data on sqlfiddle (or here) and explain what's your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple pattern that will show you the idea of how to use a `LEFT JOIN` to exclude when records are matched between to tables.  All of your join requirements should be in the "`ON`" section of the joins as the other answers/comments have mentioned other.  If you don't put them in that section and you leave them in the where clause then you would have to account for null values otherwise you will limit your query and essentially turn your results into the same as an `inner join`.  The one exception is to place a field that you always know will be `null` when not matched (e.g. Primary Key of 2nd table) into where statement and make the condition equal to `NULL`.  This is in order to exclude the records you do not want.  If you want everything then don't limit with that where clause.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,C CHAR(1)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.T2 (
    PKId INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.T1 (C)
VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')

INSERT INTO dbo.T2 (PKId)
VALUES (1),(4)

SELECT *
FROM
  dbo.T1 t1
  LEFT JOIN dbo.T2 t2
  ON t1.Id = t2.PKId
 WHERE
   t2.PKId IS NULL
```